# Can I get into a funded graduate Psychology program after having studied Chemistry?

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding, psychology

I have earned an [Honours degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honours_degree) in Chemistry, but my heart is set on Psychology.  So, I want to pursue graduate studies in Psychology.

Is it possible to get fully funded admission in a world-class university? Should I do an online course for it? If so, which one?

If it's not possible to get fully funded admission this way. How can I make myself eligible enough to get into a world-class university with a scholarship?

Please note that I have searched a lot for it but did not find any specific answer for my case.  I also found a lot of online courses for Psychology, but not sure which will help my case the most.

Comment: Welcome to SE.Academia!  I'd suggest specifying where you'd like to do your graduate studies.

Comment: What academic experience do you have in psychology (courses of any kind?)? Why are you so sure you want to study psychology? What element of psychology do you want to study/what sort of advancement would you want to make with your thesis?

Comment: any university offering world-class education will do. I prefer us/Canadian universities.  @Nat